# How to apply specific marker click function in Overlapping Marker Spiderfier for Leaflet?

Tags: typescript, leaflet, markerspiderfier, overlappingmarkerspiderfier

I have a map and some markers on that map. I have used [leaflet js](https://leafletjs.com/). Sometimes multiple markers are in the same geo location. And for this reason some markers are hidden. So to prevent that I am using [Overlapping Marker Spiderfier for Leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/overlapping-marker-spiderfier-leaflet). And that hidden issue if fixed.

I added my start marker to oms as follows,

```
oms.addMarker(startMarker);
```

But actually my markers are connected markers. That means one marker for start location and one marker for stop location. So there are always will be start-strop indicating markers. So there is a function whenever I click the start marker it is going to the stop marker. Since I have to user the overlapping marker spiderfier I had to remove that function.

Before removing the functions it was like this,

```
startMarker = L.marker(latitude, longitude], {
        icon: icon,
      }).addTo(this.map).on("click", (event) => {
        this.map.flyTo(L.latLng([stopLat, stopLong]),
          15);
      });
```

In oms there is a click event so I added the above code inside the following,

```
oms.addListener('click', (marker: any) => {

});
```

But it is not working. What it does is when I click any start marker, every start marker is going to the same stop marker. But it should go to their respective stop markers. So what I need to know is how can do that with `oms.addListener`?